# Adding a library to a target

Tags: xcode, xcode4

My documentation says

> Click on the target and add pgmName.a on General settings of the
>   target Info.

I don't see a General settings, although I see Architectures, Build Locations, etc under build settings.  And there's an info tab and a summary tab, but I don't see a General settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4 no longer has this tab setup. You'll want to add `pgmName.a` to the **Link Binary With Libraries** step under the **Build Phases** tab of the target. If you're seeing Info and Summary tabs instead of Build Settings, Build Phases, and Build Rules, click on the target rather than the project in the left panel (under **TARGETS** rather than PROJECT.)